# Kubuntu 16.04: How to disable swap partition from auto-mounting?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, kubuntu, swap, automount

I have 2 swap partitions on my drive, one for Kubuntu(/dev/sda7), the other for Kali Linux(/dev/sda9). After googling around for methods how to stop the Kali Linux swap partition from auto-mounting on startup, and trying everything, it still auto-mounts it on boot. Does anybody know how to make Kubuntu mount its swap partition, but not the other one?

My /etc/fstab file:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system>  <mount point>  <type>  <options>          <dump>  <pass>
/dev/sda5        /              ext4    errors=remount-ro  0       1
/dev/sda2        /boot/efi      vfat    umask=0077         0       1
/dev/sda6        /home          ext4    defaults           0       2
/dev/sda7        none           swap    sw                 0       0
/dev/sda9        none           swap    defaults,noauto    0       0
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: May I ask which system is this fstab file in?

Answer (score 0):

Commenting out the the line that starts with `/dev/sda9` by adding a **#** in front of it, saving and rebooting, should do the trick.